# Is there an easy way to generate a graph of Ansible role dependencies?

Tags: scalability, administration, ansible, orchestration

Since version 1.3, Ansible has supported role dependencies to encourage reuse of role definitions.  To audit and maintain larger orchestrations, it would be nice to have some way to easily generate a dependency graph of which roles depend on which other roles.

An example of dependency definitions might be `roles/app_node/meta/main.yml`:

```
---
dependencies:
  - { role: common, some_parameter: 3 }
  - { role: apache, port: 80 }
  - { role: postgres_client, 
      dbname: blarg, 
      other_parameter: 12 }
```

where `roles/postgres_client/meta/main.yml` might include something like

```
---
dependencies:
  - { role: postgres_common }
  - { role: stunnel, 
      client: yes,
      local_port: 5432
      remote_host: db_host
      remote_port: 15432 
    }
```

Such nested dependencies can get messy to maintain when the number of roles in an orchestration grows.  I therefore wonder if anyone has found an easy way to generate a graph of such dependencies, either graphically (dot or neato?) or just as an indented text graph?  Such a tool could help reduce the maintenance complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following python script worked for me:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import gv
from glob import glob
import yaml

g = gv.digraph('roles')

role_nodes = {}

def add_role(role):
    if role not in role_nodes:
        role_nodes[role] = gv.node(g, role)

def link_roles(dependent, depended):
    gv.edge(
        role_nodes[dependent_role],
        role_nodes[depended_role]
    )

for path in glob('roles/*/meta/main.yml'):
    dependent_role = path.split('/')[1]

    add_role(dependent_role)

    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        for dependency in yaml.load(f.read())['dependencies']:
            depended_role = dependency['role']

            add_role(depended_role)
            link_roles(dependent_role, depended_role)

gv.layout(g, 'dot')
gv.render(g, 'png', 'doc/ansible-roles.png')
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining _how_ it addresses the problem stated in the question.

Comment: Running: "ImportError: No module named gv".  pip install gv:   "No distributions at all found for gv"

Comment: @TravisBear The `gv` module is part of Graphviz, it is not distributed on PyPI. You can install it using the package manager of your linux distribution (apt, yum...). Package name may be something like `graphviz-python` or `python-graphviz`.

Comment: I've made an [alternative version](https://gist.github.com/sboisson/472c6af5c7e15bc24114b13f11456190) using [graphviz](https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/) python package

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) to do this like the [ginas project](https://github.com/ginas/ginas/blob/master/contrib/graphviz/ginas-role-dependencies.dot) has.

Answer (score 0):

```
# install gv on ubuntu
sudo apt-get install python3-gv
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by showing how `python-gv` answers OP's problem.

Comment: I think this should actually just be added to sebn's answer.  It seems to be the missing piece for most of those who don't get how to install `gv`.